# how to fetch the sqlite count in my list view?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, count

Is this correct code for counting the task?how to fetch these counting in my listview?// Getting contacts Count

```
public int getTaskCount() {
     String countQuery = "SELECT Count(KEY_ROWID_REL) FROM  " + DATABASE_TABLE_REL;
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
     Cursor mcursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
     mcursor.moveToFirst();

     // return count
     return mcursor.getCount();
 }    

 private SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return null;
}

public long fetchAllProjectscount(int rowId) {
   String countQuery = "SELECT Count KEY_ROWID_REL FROM  " + DATABASE_TABLE_REL;
   SQLiteStatement statement =mDb.compileStatement(countQuery);
   return (int) statement.simpleQueryForLong();     
}
```

Comment: thank you,how i want to show that count with my list view?

Comment: try to be more precise in your question and show us what you already have tried.

Comment: ok,i created one list view dynamically,while clicking the one task in that listview,it will shows the another list.what i want is?i want to show how many list in one task...

Comment: did you understand my doubt? @ cosmincalistru

Comment: and how is this list view related to the database? put more examples from your code. because the initial question is about a count in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is wrong, here is correct one:

```
SELECT Count(KEY_ROWID_REL) FROM DATABASE_TABLE_REL;
```

Comment: thank you,but i want how to fetch this count with my keytitle in list view

Comment: String[] from = new String[]{ProjectsDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE};      here how i will fetch the title with count as visible